# Is it acceptable to ask for the original bibtex file of a paper?

Tags: publications, citations, etiquette, latex

I am reading a review paper which includes hundreds of useful citations for my paper. I would like to import some of the citations into a bibtex file. The only thing I know to do is to search them on google one by one, and then click on "export bibtex".

Is it acceptable (ethical) to ask the author of a paper for the original bibtex (Latex) file?

Or I wonder if there are any program could do the repetitive job: searching each citation on google one by one and export the bibtex from google scholar.

---

Thanks for the Scopus answer. It works for most of the published (not working papers, though) papers!!

Comment: If you just ask for the bibtex file rather than the rest of the latex source, it might be seen more positively.  On the other hand, some people use one giant bibtex file for all their projects, and might not like to share with you the list of every paper they have ever looked at.

Comment: I agree with Nate, I would be happy to provide the .bib source of my references.

Comment: It would be kind of weird, though I probably would share it if asked.  FYI: If the paper is posted to the arXiv, you can download the source from there without asking the author.

Comment: @Nate: you could provide the .blg

Comment: You mean .bbl?  That is only useful if you want to use exactly the same citation style as me.  (By the way, I think arXiv only needs the .bbl as well, so @AndyPutman's suggestion may suffer from the same issue.)

Comment: The title of this question currently says "original Latex file", which makes it sound like you're asking for the source of the whole paper. That is a rather different request than source for the bibliography, and I would recommend editing your question to clarify the title.

Comment: **Qiqqa** would allow to speed up the reference searching, reading and collections process, if you are looking for a Windows tool (with Google support).

Comment: @NateEldredge _"That's [.bbl] only useful if you want to use exactly the same citation style as me."_ I have to disagree. Parsing a bbl file to get an approximation of the bibtex references sounds like a straightforward task task compared to many other hacks I've been doing to get some data in a nice form. Yes, many things might result in an error, but it's still easier to correct those than to download the bibtex files one by one.

Comment: Shouldn't you manually go over the cited papers and include those relevant, not just dump a lot of unread citations into your paper?

Comment: @Matsemann Bibtex automatically includes in the reference list only the papers that have actually been cited in your document. So it's perfectly fine to use a monster `.bib` file containing lots of paper in your area (and some people actually do it).

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with ethics.

Comment: @NateEldredge: "On the other hand, some people use one giant bibtex file". In that case I would suggest to use [`aux2bib`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtools) to create a `bib`-file containing exactly the referenced items.

Comment: For what it's worth, it shouldn't be terribly hard to write a program to do this (at least approximately) given the pdf or dvi file.

Comment: Not unethical - just lazy

Comment: Edited the question title! Asking for the LaTeX of the body is one thing, asking for the bibliography is another.

Comment: I put my own master bibtex file on line and see no issue in anyone using it, there is nothing embarrassing in divulging this file!

Comment: **Hundreds**??? I think that my Ph.D. has 34 references, and that includes *a lot* of overlap (each chapter has its own bibliographic section, and there are cross-references between the chapters). Sure, I wrote a very specific thesis. But nonetheless, **hundreds** sounds like you are writing a series of books, not "my paper" (singular!!!)...

Comment: @Inkblot It depends on the discipline. In pure math it is very common to have less than 10 references; in econ or finance, even some undergrad paper have more than 100 citations. It is common for a serious econ paper to have more than 10 pages of citation!

Comment: Jesus... 10 pages of references??? My god...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I would consider this a perfectly reasonable, if unusual, request.

That probably has a lot to do with the culture of my field; most papers in particle physics are uploaded to [arXiv](https://arxiv.org) as LaTeX source (though `.bib` files are often not included), which is then made available to download along with the rendered PDF. This facilitates a cultural expectation that source code to the paper should be available to readers, not hidden. So I would consider sharing the BibTeX file associated with a paper to be a reasonable thing to do, a professional courtesy of sorts - similar to what sharing a copy of the paper itself is or used to be.

Other fields may think differently. Still, in most cases I would think it's fine to *ask*. The author can always say no or ignore your request, if they don't want their file to be shared for some reason.

Comment: This. I actually do make sources of my papers freely available on my website, .tex and .bib files both. I honestly have no idea why anyone would make a fuss about it. I sometimes *do* look at .tex files of other people's papers (on arXiv) to see how they typeset something. Sure, sometimes I found slightly embarrassing hacks, but it's not such a big deal. ;-)

Comment: @tomasz Sure, if it's *already* available either on arxiv.org or because the author posts the source themselves, the question is moot. But presumably the situation here is that the source has *not* been made publicly available.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning: my point is, I don't see what the big deal is about making it publicly available in the first place. That or sending a copy to someone. This is of course different if you don't have access to the source for whatever reasons, but otherwise...

Comment: @Elizabeth FWIW the `.bib` files are often not included in the source uploaded to arXiv.

Comment: I agree, this has to be related to the expectation of different fields of research. It is such a reasonable and simple request, I can not imagine anyone saying "*no, I will not send you the .bib file of the article, even though the article is already published*".

Comment: @Gabriel - sure, unless it appears to take some time to prepare the bib file for it to be 'ready' for random consumption. (remove extraneous items, or at least check and get rid of any 'review' or 'note' comments associated with entries that might not be notations that one would want distribute.

Comment: @Carol I've never added any comments or notes to my .bib files, but if that's the case removing them can not be such a time consuming task. If it indeed is, then sure, you are not *obligated* to take the time.

Comment: (upvote) Works!

Comment: It would be inconvenient for me to share the .bib file in my publications. The reason is that I have a huge .bib file with all the papers that I am using / have used / am interested in, and use it as source for all my Latex files. The .tex, of course, should always be shared instead.

Answer (score 36):

My feeling about this is that if you don't personally know the author, it's weird and tacky and will probably result in being ignored. Even if you do personally know the author, it's still kind of weird and tacky. But there's nothing unethical about it.

Comment: (upvote) I think it is a little bit awkward, too. Is it better to mention this in a friendly, personal chat (if this is an option)?

Comment: @HighGPA You're basically asking someone to (1) share their working documents with you for the purpose of (2) saving you some work which is really your own responsibility. I'm not saying you should categorically not do it, but it could be seen as very presumptuous depending on your relationship with the author.

Comment: "*weird and tacky*"? I can honestly not think of a single reason why anyone would consider sharing the sources of a published article (which are *already* public) either "weird" or "tacky"... I guess this must be related to the different disciplines of research.

Comment: I disagree.  Reusing a bibtex file would be an example of working efficiently, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 25):

As an alternative solution, if your institution has access to Scopus, you can find the paper there and see the citation list and export it in Bibtex. Web of Science has a similar feature.

To answer your question, however, it is not really unethical, but would likely be seen as a weird request.

Comment: (upvote) My current school only gives the access to Scopus's competitor, Web of Sci. Does Web of Sci has similar function?

Comment: Yes, you can find the paper and click on "Cited References". That will give you the bibliography and allow you to export them. You can't do it directly as a Bibtex, but you can output to a couple of bibliography management software, or output the raw citation data which isn't difficult to convert to bibtex.

Comment: Thanks! Luckily I have the access to Scopus through my another affiliation. The only problem is the most useful review paper is most likely a working paper which is not documented by Scopus......

Comment: @HighGPA If it isn't published, how do you have access to it? If you are reviewing the paper, I would say it is definitely unethical to ask. That would be a whole different scenario. Or do you mean it is a working paper somebody has published unofficially e.g. a draft on an author's web site?

Comment: @cfr Yes, I mean the working papers.

Comment: The `.bib` files produced by Scopus/WoS/Google Scholar are not directly usable without manual editing. They get a lot of things wrong (capitalization, name/surname splitting, special characters...).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni That's true of pretty much any online citation source. Plus there's no guarantee the authors of the paper in question got all the citations completely right too considering the number of citations in question.

Comment: @JAB I am not sure of what you are trying to tell me with this comment. Do we agree that grabbing someone else's bibtex file (with a useful selection of references, human-readable keys, and some manual edits to fix at least glaring mistakes such as those that cause compilation errors) requires a lot less work than trying to produce a new one from automated sources from the internet?

Answer (score 6):

The context can often make a big difference. If you are an experienced researcher, then this request would be seen as weird and possibly annoying since you could easily find these .bib sources yourself without bothering busy people. However, if you make it clear in your request that you are a high school student without proper [experience and] resources, and also make clear that you don't want them to go to any bother to accommodate your request, then I think that most people would be happy to help, and it wouldn't be awkward.

Comment: I know how to produce the bib source by myself. But I am not sure if it is "easy" to find the bib source by myself?

Comment: In your situation, where you might not have proper resources [or experience], I would not call it "easy" for you - so it would fine for you to email a request for help. On the other hand, if you were a professional researcher, then you would have resources and experience that would allow you to create the bib source yourself "easily", so an email request would be far less appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Arxiv API that can be used for this purpose.

You can read the [documentation](https://arxiv.org/help/api/index) and programmatically make requests for the papers that you need, asking for the various fields as an output. You can send these requests as you want from the browser or any other programming language. In python for instance you can use [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request).

Furthermore, someone already did this and it is [freely available on github](https://github.com/nathangrigg/arxiv2bib).

For physicists there is an alternative using the [INSPIRE](https://inspirehep.net/) API that is documented [here](https://github.com/inspirehep/rest-api-doc). It can be used to automatically request for the bibtex entry without the need of composing it by hand by reading the various fields.

Comment: No, I should have explained better. An API is a service that websites offer you to programmatically request data from them (with some limitations of course). This means that you can write an URL that says "Arxiv, give me the bibtex citation data for the papers with id 2011.12345, 2011.12346, ...". Which will return either an html page, a json file or a text file with the data requested. And then you can make a python script that generates said url automatically.

Comment: Truly sorry about misunderstanding you! Does you method only works for sites like Arxiv or for any journal articles?